# Get String instead of Number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ionic3

I'm working on a quiz app that is based on a 'string' answered instead of the variable 'number'. I tried different syntax but it just displays a blank with no data/error displayed. As you can see my code below, I'll give you an example logic that I want.

```
if(answer.correct == "answerstring"){displayvariable == "STRINGTOBEDISPLAYED"};
```

Here is my 'question.json'

```
{
    "questions": [

        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/questionimg/12_plate1.gif' />",
            "flashCardBack": "12",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What number is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "12", "correct": true, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "17", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "NOTHING", "correct": false, "selected": false}
            ]
        },
        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/questionimg/8_plate2.gif' />",
            "flashCardBack": "8",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What is number is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "3", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "8", "correct": true, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "NOTHING", "correct": false, "selected": false}
            ]
        },
        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/questionimg/29_plate3.gif' />",
            "flashCardBack": "29",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "70", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "NOTHING", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "29", "correct": true, "selected": false}
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

My data.ts where my dataprovider is located.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/*
  Generated class for the DataProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {


  data: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  load(){

    if(this.data){
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.http.get('assets/data/questions.json').subscribe((data:any) => {
            this.data = data.questions;
            resolve(this.data);
      });

    });

  }

}
```

My typescript where the quiz is being processed

```
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';

/**
 * Generated class for the IshiharaQuestionsPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-ishihara-questions',
  templateUrl: 'ishihara-questions.html',
})

export class IshiharaQuestionsPage {

  @ViewChild('slides') slides: any;

    hasAnswered: boolean = false;
    score: number = 0;
    cvd: string;

    slideOptions: any;
    questions: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: DataProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);

    this.dataService.load().then((data) => {

        data.map((question) => {

            let originalOrder = question.answers;
            question.answers = this.randomizeAnswers(originalOrder);
            return question;

        });     

        this.questions = data;

    });

  }

  nextSlide(){
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  selectAnswer(answer, question){

    this.hasAnswered = true;
    answer.selected = true;
    question.flashCardFlipped = true;

    if(answer.correct){
        this.score++;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.hasAnswered = false;
        this.nextSlide();
        answer.selected = false;
        question.flashCardFlipped = false;
    }, 3000);
  }


  randomizeAnswers(rawAnswers: any[]): any[] {

    for (let i = rawAnswers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = rawAnswers[i];
        rawAnswers[i] = rawAnswers[j];
        rawAnswers[j] = temp;
    }

    return rawAnswers;

  }

  restartQuiz() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideTo(1, 1000);
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
}
```

and this is where I want to display that string.

```
<ion-slide>
        <ion-card>
          <h2 text-justify padding>The 24 plate quiz suggests that you might currenly belong to this CVD type:</h2>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1 color="danger">{{cvd}}</h1> <<-----------------THIS LINE
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h2>Final Score: {{score}}/24</h2>
          <button (click)="restartQuiz()" ion-button full color="primary">Start Again</button>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
```

Comment: According to json `correct` is boolean. not string or number

Comment: your response give you boolean value so use **if(answer.correct){displayvariable = "STRINGTOBEDISPLAYED"};**

Comment: any idea on how to turn boolean to string with the same variable? i'm just new to ionic and any component of it like json. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ionic syntax are basically uses TypeScript or more specifically similar to Angular (JS/2+) code, in Angular(JS/2+) for string comparison or to check equality we use '===' (triple equal to) rather '=='. Please replace '==' with '===', and it should be working OK.